# No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0

Tags: spring-mvc, glassfish, jta, entitymanager

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my config? I'm overly frustrated and I've been loosing my hair on this. Any pointer will be welcome. 
Thanks

**Persistence.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>             
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/oracle</jta-data-source>              
        <class>com.myproject.domain.UserAccount</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>                       
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC" />
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Oracle10g"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="NONE"/>

            <!--Integrate EclipseLink with JTA in Glassfish-->
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="SunAS9"/>

            <property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="0"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>

        </properties>   

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>MyProject</display-name>

    <persistence-unit-ref>
        <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/myPersistenceUnit</persistence-unit-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>myPersistenceUnit</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-unit-ref>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>      

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd" default-autowire="byName">



    <tx:annotation-driven/>         
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager/>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence/myPersistenceUnit"/>  


    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>    
     <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <!-- enables interpretation of the @PersistenceUnit/@PersistenceContext annotations providing convenient  
       access to EntityManagerFactory/EntityManager -->         
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>


</beans>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myProject" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

    <!-- Location Tiles config -->
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" 
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">     
         <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</value>
            </list>
         </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by Tiles -->
    <bean id="tilesViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"
          p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

</beans>
```

**UserAccountDAO.java**

```
@Repository
public class UserAccountDAO implements IUserAccountDAO {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public UserAccount checkLogin(String userName, String pwd) {        
        //* Find the user in the DB             
        Query queryUserAccount = entityManager.createQuery("select u from UserAccount u where (u.username = :userName) and (u.password = :pwd)");
.......
    }
```

}

**loginController.java**

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"userAccount"})
public class LoginLogOutController  {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserAccount.class);

    @Resource
    private UserAccountDAO userDAO; 

    @RequestMapping(value="/loginForm.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String showloginForm(Map model) {         
        logger.debug("Get login form"); 
        UserAccount userAccount = new UserAccount();                        
        model.put("userAccount", userAccount);
        return "loginform";
    }
...
```

**Error Stack**

```
INFO: 13:52:21,657 ERROR ContextLoader:220 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userAccountDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4664)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:535)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5266)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1947)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1619)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:732)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is

`<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence/myPersistenceUnit"/>`

don't you need to tell spring what interface this implements? Or maybe not. Looking through my own code I don't sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting a reference to the ApplicationContext instead. And do a lookup of the entitymanager by name. Make sure it implements the interface you are expecting. Might be a classloader missmatch?

Comment: according to the [reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/orm.html#orm-jpa-setup-jndi), it seems like there is no much to do besides `<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence/myPersistenceUnit"/>`. I tried all sort of combination without success. The application is able to locate the JNDI and instantiate the bean but for some reasons the issue comes up when I tried to inject the persistence in the DAO and also when I try to use @Autowired or @Resource in the DAO. @Konstantin Thanks for trying I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new at the Spring framework configuration, but trying to help another fellow here at the site, I found the bellow Spring+JPA tutorial (a fine translated from pt-br by google). I found it really clarifying mainly because it tries to explain good practices when using these two technologies together:

http://translate.google.com.br/translate?hl=en&sl=pt&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Ffabiolnm.blogspot.com%2F2009%2F11%2Fintegracao-spring-x-jpa.html

Wish it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the site. It is really appreciated and does reinforce my understanding of all this. Still can't figure out what in the world is wrong with my config....GGGrrrrrr!!!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with a different jndi-name path? I've see elsewhere this notation:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" "entityManagerFactory"
    jndi-name="java:comp/env/persistence/myPersistenceUnit"></jee:jndi-lookup>
```

seems that some class needs the standard lookup path for jndi names